# Help identifying mystery device in ceiling

Tags: electrical-panel, ceiling

[image]Unidentified device in ceiling

We have been renovating a recently purchased home, built in 2002.  The painter removed the cover from this device while prepping to paint ceiling.  It is located in ceiling near front entryway.  Nobody (contractor, electrician) have been able to identify what it is?

It is not related to the doorbell, electrician confirmed.

Comment: Your general location in the world might help.  It almost looks to be adjustable.  Can you add a picture of the cover?

Comment: We are located in Scottsdale, Arizona, U.S.

Unfortunately the cover has disappeared since painter removed.

Comment: This could be a humidistat. I remember seeing something like this in my grandfather's house, but I can't find a picture.

Comment: What sort of cable is that blue cable?  It looks like an RJ45 (i.e. Ethernet).  Do you recognize that sort of cabling for elsewhere in your house, such as thermostat controls or home security?  It's obviously built into your house, so in theory you should be able to find other similar cabling elsewhere.  It reminds me of a unusual heating/cooling system that I saw one time that had two separate temperature sensors, one for heating and one for cooling, but that wasn't in a house situation.

Answer (score 17):

Google reverse image search for the win!

[Legrand DA1101 wireless access point](https://assets.twacomm.com/assets/pdf/43706.pdf)

Comment: I did a google image search too, must not have scrolled far enough...

Comment: Interesting. I think I might have been using google lens with a zoomed in version. And for what it’s worth, I totally thought it was a humidistat.